# Does PayPal do refunding and cancel refunding on direct payments with credit card?

Tags: paypal

I know refunding and cancel refunding is what is possible with PayPal using a PayPal account. Is it possible also for direct payments with credit card? On the web application I am developing it is possible to pay with a PayPal account and directly with your credit card(using PayPal services).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible according to [this page](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/article/?solutionId=FAQ1083&m=HTQ).